# Actions are being passed to state object and the actions object is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Problem Description**

Using the connect function from react-redux and params mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps which are supposed to set the state and actions, the component is successfully being constructed however in the component the actions are being passed into state instead of actions.

```
class Example extends Component{

    constructor(state, actions){
        super();        
        console.log(state); // object containing both state and actions 
        console.log(actions); // empty object
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Below is what is printed when `console.log(state);` is called from the constructor

```
{
    state_X:val, 
    state_Y:val, 
    actions:{
        action_X: action_X(),
        ...
    }
}
```

Code to pass state and actions (bottom of same file)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {...state};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    let bounded = bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
    console.log(bounded); // object with actions {action_X:action_X(), ...}
    return {actions: bounded};
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Example);
```

Here is how the app is created and the component loaded

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,    
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware, // lets us dispatch() functions
        loggerMiddleware // neat middleware that logs actions
    )
);

class App extends Component{
    render(){       
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/example" component={Example}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        ); 
    }
}

render( 
    <Provider store={store}>    
        <App/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Dependencies from `package.json`

```
"react": "^16.4.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are seeing actually is right.

all actions and redux state is comes under `props`

in this case you have used it as `state`

as an example you can use :

```
this.props.actions.actionX()
```

to call you actionX()

and

you can have your stateX using

```
this.props.state_X
```

here is the documentation for using constructor: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

and finally

> you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs

since I saw you using it without `super(props)`

hope this will help you.

Comment: Your reinforcement led me to my answer, while reviewing the redux docs, https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components, I realized they were using a spread in the constructor... I was not, I mistook it for two separate objects. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The constructor, as gluttony reinforced in his answer, aggregates all params into one object, I thought the `react-redux` `connect` function loaded the state and actions into two separate objects however I was not observant and did not see there were using a spread.

so this

```
constructor(state, actions){
```

should have been

```
constructor({actions, ...state}){
```